# TypeError: Subprocess on linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am using subprocess in python and getting this error using on linux (python 3.7.3), but on windows (python 3.7.4) it works.

Traceback:

```
Tool started in terminal
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "main.py", line 53, in start
    obj = subprocess.Popen([self.Tipvar.get(), 'mytool.py', *filter(lambda x: bool(x[1]) ,(firstarg, secondarg, secondarg, thirdarg))])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1453, in _execute_child
    restore_signals, start_new_session, preexec_fn)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple
```

The code I am using to start this subprocess is:

```
 def start(self):
        firstarg = ("--first-arg ", self.first_arg_entry.get())
        secondarg =   ("--second-arg ", self.second_arg_entry.get())
        thirdarg = ("--third-arg ", self.third_arg_entry.get())
        print ("Tool started in terminal")
        self.bt_stop.config(state=NORMAL)
        self.bt_start.config(state=DISABLED)        
        global obj
        obj = subprocess.Popen([self.Tipvar.get(), 'mytool.py', *filter(lambda x: bool(x[1]) ,(firstarg, secondarg, secondarg, thirdarg))])
```

Why this code does not work in linux? How to make it works on Win/Linux/Mac?

Comment: could you provide a full backtrace?

Comment: @HanxiFu thanks for replying, traceback added!

Comment: you shouldn't use `(firstarg, secondarg, secondarg, thirdarg)` in `Popen`, removing the parathenses may help

Comment: @HanxiFu didnt catch it! I need that arguments when Popen

Comment: you mean you have to pass this tuple as one argument through the command line? only remove the parentheses, keep those arguments. In fact, you can't receive a tuple from cmd, right?

Comment: @HanxiFu is that you mean?

`obj = subprocess.Popen([self.Tipvar.get(), 'mytool.py', *filter(lambda x: bool(x[1]) ,firstarg, secondarg, secondarg, thirdarg])` If i do it i get a SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Yes. Besides, I think you may also need to check your python version on Windows again. If it's python2, then it makes sense why your tuple still works.

Comment: If you're pretty sure your windows run python 3.7.4, then it makes no sense... I don't know why it worked.

Comment: @HanxiFu After closing a ) of the lambda on `obj = subprocess.Popen([self.Tipvar.get(), 'mytool.py', *filter(lambda x: bool(x[1]) ,firstarg, secondarg, secondarg, thirdarg)])` I got TypeError: filter expected 2 arguments, got 13

Comment: damn...I made a mistake. I thought these tuples are not in your filter sentence. I'm totally wrong. sorry for your time. I'll think about it again and answer below if I figure it out

Comment: @HanxiFu i m sure that windows is running python 3.7.4, i still dont understand where is my error.

Comment: @HanxiFu dont worries and thanks for trying help me. I m not sure if my question is clear to understanding, may i edit it?

Comment: I think it's pretty okay. It was just me not paying enough attention...

Comment: Why are you running Python as a subprocess of Python anyway? Probably just refactor `mytool.py` so you can `import` it directly.

Comment: @tripleee its a UI to start another tool, single file that start this tool at same terminal... thats is the necessity on this case.

Comment: Sounds like exactly a reason to not run it in a subprocess.

Answer (score 0):

this is because you're assign `firstarg`, `secondarg`, `thirdarg` as tuples.

take this as an example:

```
firstarg = ('--first-arg', 'a')
secondarg = ('--second-arg', 'a')
thirdarg = ('--third-arg', 'a')

a = [*filter(lambda x: bool(x[1]), (firstarg, secondarg, secondarg, thirdarg))]
```

Here you got `[('--first-arg', 'a'), ('--second-arg', 'a'), ('--second-arg', 'a'), ('--third-arg', 'a')]`, so it will report error `not tuple` error.

You need to expand the tuples.

My suggestions:

```py
import itertools

arguments = list(itertools.chain(*filter(lambda x: bool(x[1]), (firstarg, secondarg, secondarg, thirdarg))))
obj = subprocess.Popen([self.Tipvar.get(), 'mytool.py', *arguments])
```

As the reason why windows works... still have no idea. maybe edit later if I figure it out.

Comment: Still not working after adding your your suggestions:

        `firstarg = ("--first-arg ", self.first_arg_entry.get())
        secondarg =   ("--second-arg ", self.second_arg_entry.get())
        thirdarg = ("--third-arg ", self.third_arg_entry.get())
        print ("Tool started in terminal")
        self.bt_stop.config(state=NORMAL)
        self.bt_start.config(state=DISABLED)        
        global obj
arguments = list(itertools.chain(*filter(lambda x: bool(x[1]), (firstarg, secondarg, secondarg, thirdarg))))
obj = subprocess.Popen([self.Tipvar.get(), 'mytool.py', *arguments])`

Comment: NameError: name 'itertools' is not defined

Comment: import itertools

Comment: after importe itertools it seem that will work but... getting:
`Unknown arguments: --first-arg , jack rose paul, --second-arg , 3, --third-arg , 150`

its considering a coma (,) between arg and its value.... something that was not happening with original code.

@HanxiFu any idea?

Comment: I still dont have find a solution for it.

Comment: how do you write your `mytool.py`? normally if you use argparse with these arguments it shouldn't be an issue